# Flutter is giving me Android ID which is different from original Android ID

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am using this code here the android id or device id I am getting , I don't know where it is located on the phone but when I am getting the device ID is different Please guide me.

```
 Future<String?> getDeviceDetails() async {



final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = new DeviceInfoPlugin();
AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo;

try {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    var build = await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo;
    androidInfo = build;




    uniqueId = (await PlatformDeviceId.getDeviceId)!;
    //uniqueId = await DeviceId.getID;


    setState(() {
       deviceName = build.model;
       deviceVersion = build.version.toString();

       identifier = build.id;
     });

     return uniqueId;

    //UUID for Android
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    var data = await deviceInfoPlugin.iosInfo;
    setState(() {
    deviceName = data.name;
    deviceVersion = data.systemVersion;
    identifier = data.identifierForVendor;  //UUID for iOS
    });
    print(identifier);
    return identifier;
  }
} on PlatformException {
  print('Failed to get platform version');

  return "";
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you call "Original Device ID" ?

If you mean "IMEI" it cannot be retrieved anymore due to security concerns : https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids Only system apps can

So what you get with device_info plugin is just a generated uniq device ID, but keep in ming that it can be easily manipulated (root) or reseted on a factory reset ..

Comment: Can you please give me a guide where this uniq device id is located on the phone where it is showing.